# Joomla: Why is the "Extension Manager" menu item not showing in the "Extensions" drop down menu?

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

As per the title. I am running Joomla 2.5.

The only items visible in the "Extensions" drop down menu are:

- Module Manager
- Plug-in Manager
- Template Manager
- Language Manager

**EDIT**: I am doing this for the purpose of installing a template, as per the instructions on this page: [http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Installing_a_template](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aInstalling_a_template)

Comment: Are you a super administrator on the sie?

Comment: No, I'm just a regular administrator.

Comment: You probably do not have permission to install extensions. As a super admin to raise your permissions.

Answer (score 2):

As Elin's comment suggests, you must be a super user in order for this menu item to display.